# Airflow creates duplicates exactly once

Tags: python, airflow

I wrote a DAG that runs once per day at 07:30AM but so far can't figure out why it duplicate each row exactly once. I pass `execution_date` to the SQL query so it shouldn't be an issue.

The DAG logic (please ignore any grammar error):

It first runs `DELETE FROM table_target WHERE EventDate >= {'previous_date'}` that is it deletes all data from `execution_date - 1`.

It then runs `INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM some_subquery WHERE EventDate >= {'previous_date'} AND EventDate <= {'current_date'}`, where `current_date` is exactly `execution_date`.

So the logic is summarized as: First delete all data from yesterday, and insert all data since yesterday. Bhy doing this I can do real-time streaming without worrying about duplication or missing data. This logic works when I use `cron`.

Somehow in Airflow this is creating duplications for each row, once per row, for each `execution_date` except for the first date. So if I run it from 2021-02-01, ONLY 2021-02-01 has good data, and every date afterwards has exactly the double amount of correct data.

Can someone shed light what could be the reason? Thanks! The source sub query has no duplications as I also run a copy using `cron`. This second `cron` version insert data into another table so it's not the issue.

Comment: `current_date` & `previous_date` are not Airflow terms. Please define them. If current_date is today `datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` or something of that kind what you are describing is expected because you are using dates wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using `execution_date` for `current_date` so that's not an issue. I actually found the issue that the Airflow account does not have permission to the `DELETE` command. I tried `TRUNCATE TABLE` and `DROP PARTITIONS` instead and it's working. Now I wonder why Airflow doesn't give any warning regarding that, or maybe I should fetch from the return message? The log doesn't say anything regarding a permission issue.

Comment: Probably because the underlying package of the db isnt raising exception for that case. If you found a bug in Airflow you are welcome to open a PR to fix it.